# Autoit MouseClick not successfully clicking

Tags: autoit

I am attempting to make an automation for a browser game on kongregate, minequest. I've created a code that is supposed to click a series of buttons however while the mouse moves, the mouse doesn't always successfully click. No errors are given and each time I run the code different clicks fail. I have tried adding more and more time between clicks to the point that I now have 1 second wait times, repeat the clicks at least twice, etc. to try to ensure a click happens but clicks still don't always happen.

I have windows 10, mouse pointer scheme is set to none, I am using google chrome as the browser.

Edit: FYI I have made other automations that work just same with the same browser, same computer, etc. I currently have gotten this code working by having it click 10 times instead of 1 but that shouldn't be necessary and I would like to understand why this phenomenon is happening.

Comment: tried `mousedown`, `sleep`, `mouseup` ?

Comment: @Stephan Haven't tried that. I have always used mouseclick. This is the first time I've ever had an issue with it.

Comment: Probably that special game doesn't react on "click", but on button status. `MouseClick` might not have enough time between "Press" and "Release" for the game to notice that the button is "down". Your description supports that oppinion. If you don't have trouble with a mouseclick "by hand", a sleep time of 100 - 200 ms should be fine.

Comment: When I asked my friend to test some script I wrote, appeared, that some clicks were missing, while other worked fine. Debugging revealed, that PC was way too slow and I needed to increase mouse move speed (last param in MouseClick) and set larger delay between clicks with `AutoItSetOption("MouseClickDelay", $some_value)`

Comment: @Stephan I finally got around to testing it out although in a different game with a similar issue and using mousedown, sleep, then mouseup did indeed work consistently. Mind putting your comment into an answer so I can accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes an application might not react on "click", but on "button status". `MouseClick` might not have enough time between "Press" and "Release" for those applications to notice that the button is "down". (Your description ("working one time out of two to ten") supports this oppinion). To give that application a proper "Button is down", a `mousedown`, `sleep`, `mouseup` sequence should work.

If you don't have trouble with a mouseclick "by hand", a sleep time of 100 - 200 ms should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem, and it turned out that some programs didn't register my clicks because by default, Autoit only holds down the mouse click for 10ms, which wasn't long enough for it to register on some programs.

Setting

```
 Opt("MouseClickDownDelay",50)
```

fixed it, by increasing the length of each click to 50 milliseconds.

Comment: Same effect as my answer, but more elegant. Although it extents *all* mouse clicks (which is probably fine for this usecase)